# Quantum answer self-interference

Tags: support, bug, answers

I just posted an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25299893/18157).  When I clicked the "Post Your Answer" button, I saw the orange banner saying "1 new answer posted, click to reload," and my answer was still open in the editor, so I clicked "Post Your Answer" again.

Then I got a message saying my answer appeared to be a duplicate.  It seems my answer went through a two-slit screen and interfered with itself before striking the SO page and having its wave function collapsed to a single post.  I would have expected a nice moiré interference pattern but I guess SO is *above* quantum mechanical rules.

Is this indicative of a race condition between the front end and back end?

Comment: I've also experienced this.

Comment: In race conditions involving the frontend and backend, the backend tends to lose.  Unless you're racing backwards, in which case it tends to win.

Comment: I guess the questions is whether it was one post traveling forwards in time or two posts traveling backwards.